# Find if any value from a list exists anywhere in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of specific company identifications numbers.
ex. companyID = ['1','2','3']

and I have a dataframe of different attributes relating to company business.
ex. company_df

There are multiple columns where values from my list could be.
ex. 'company_number', 'company_value', 'job_referred_by', etc.

How can I check if any value from my companyID list exists anywhere in my company_df, regardless of datatype, and return only the columns where a companyID is found?

This is what I have tried, to no luck:

```
def find_any(company_df, companyID):
    found = company_df.isin(companyID).any()
    foundCols = found.index[found].tolist()
    print(foundCols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a df from your list of companyIDs and then merge the two dfs on company ID.  Then filter the df to show only the rows that match.

For datatypes, you can convert int to string no problem, but the other way around would crash if you have a string that can't be converted to int (e.g., 'a'), so I'd use string.

Here's a toy example:

```
company_df = pd.DataFrame({'co_id':  [1, 2, 4, 9]})

company_df['co_id'] = company_df['co_id'].astype(str)

companyID = ['1','2','3']
df_companyID = pd.DataFrame(companyID, columns=['co_id'])

company_df = company_df.merge(df_companyID, on='co_id', how='left', indicator=True)
print(company_df)
#   co_id     _merge
# 0     1       both
# 1     2       both
# 2     4  left_only
# 3     9  left_only

company_df_hits_only = company_df[company_df['_merge'] == 'both']
del company_df['_merge']
del company_df_hits_only['_merge']

print(company_df_hits_only)
#   co_id
# 0     1
# 1     2
```